# Notification Area Icons

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

[Ad Block FAQ](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-faq)

> How can I make the icon in the notification area go away?
>
> We hear you, the icon is a bit annoying. But right now, it has to be there - otherwise > the Android system will just stop the app, and it won't be able to block ads anymore. > We have added an option to hide it - this is the best we can do.

[This Question](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=92467.0) on Avast Forums says:

> Android stops services that are not "necessary". The icon avoid it.

My question: With AdBlock, Avast and other "services" running, the bar remains "full". Even if you "hide" the icons (like is available in AdBlock), it results in blank spaces that sully the look (First world problem I know). You can Disable the icon with Avast but it warns you of the obviously impending doom that can possibly maybe descend on you (`The icon helps Avast! protect your device better. Are you **SURE** you want to turn it off?`)

I'd like to be able to disable these without the fear of Android killing said service. With 4.3 and 4.4, are there any new options to remove those icons without fear?